# Help with string manipulation

Tags: c#, string

I am doing some data manipulation and logging records that has been updated and their fields.

I have simplified the example below but basically I append rows to a stringbuilder and then write it to a text file

I append rows with:

```
changedValues.AppendLine(string.Format("NEW VALUE: {0} | OLD VALUE {1}", Customer1.name, Customer2.name));
changedValues.AppendLine(string.Format("NEW VALUE: {0} | OLD VALUE {1}", Customer1.number, Customer2.number));
changedValues.AppendLine(string.Format("NEW VALUE: {0} | OLD VALUE {1}", Customer1.phone, Customer2.phone))
```

My issue is that name, phone and number (plus many more) have different lengths so the log file looks something like:

```
NEW VALUE: blabla | OLD VALUE blablabla
NEW VALUE: 123123123123123 | OLD VALUE 134
NEW VALUE: 213213232 | OLD VALUE 12333322333
```

which makes it more difficult to read than if it looked something like:

```
NEW VALUE: blabla          | OLD VALUE blablabla
NEW VALUE: 123123123123123 | OLD VALUE 134
NEW VALUE: 213213232       | OLD VALUE 12333322333
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Although it depends on the lengths of `Customer1.*` fields, but you can use `\t` (or many of them, depending on the maximum length): `string.Format("NEW VALUE: {0}\t|...", ...)`.

Answer (score 2):

You should define in advance the longest possible first value. For example 20:

```
sb.AppendFormat("NEW VALUE: {0,-20}| OLD VALUE {1}\r\n", Customer1.name, Customer2.name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Composite formating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx)

```
changedValues.AppendLine(string.Format("NEW VALUE: {0:-20} | OLD VALUE {1}", Customer1.name, Customer2.name));
```

Format is `{ index[,alignment][:formatString]}`

> The optional alignment component is a
>   signed integer indicating the
>   preferred formatted field width. If
>   the value of alignment is less than
>   the length of the formatted string,
>   alignment is ignored and the length of
>   the formatted string is used as the
>   field width. The formatted data in the
>   field is right-aligned if alignment is
>   positive and left-aligned if alignment
>   is negative. If padding is necessary,
>   white space is used. The comma is
>   required if alignment is specified.

Answer (score 0):

```
Customer1.name.PadRight(15, ' ')
```

And do the same for the other values.

Answer (score 0):

Use PadRight like this example:

```
static void Main()
{
string[] a = new string[]
{
    "cat",
    "poodle",
    "lizard",
    "frog",
    "photon"
};

// Output the header.
Console.Write("Key".PadRight(15));
Console.WriteLine("Value");

// Output array.
foreach (string s in a)
{
    Console.Write(s.PadRight(15));
    Console.WriteLine("noun");
}
}
Output

Key            Value
cat            noun
poodle         noun
lizard         noun
frog           noun
photon         noun
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the maximum width of your values, you can use [String.PadRight()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padright.aspx).